# include dot files (.x) with rsync -r command

Tags: bash, shell-script, rsync, wildcards

I have the following command:

```
rsync -r --exclude="node_modules" "/r2g_shared_dir/vamoot"/* "/home/node/.docker_r2g_cache/b640e7fd-27a7-4dd8-8ca8-5363a1c59c35"
```

I just realized that using /* will not copy over dot files (files/folders that start with .)...

Anybody know how I can include those files?

I assume the best way would be to forgo the /* notation and just use

```
rsync -r --exclude="node_modules" "/r2g_shared_dir/vamoot" "/home/node/.docker_r2g_cache/b640e7fd-27a7-4dd8-8ca8-5363a1c59c35"
```

but is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is bash you can just set `dotglob`:

```
shopt -s dotglob
```

This does not match `.` or `..` (in contrast to `.*`).

So the same command could be used:

```
rsync -r --exclude="node_modules" "/r2g_shared_dir/vamoot"/* ...
```

Comment: So I would do: `rsync -r "/r2g_shared_dir/vamoot"/.*` ??

Comment: @AlexanderMills No, see the edit. Sorry, I thought that was obvious.

Comment: ah sorry now I get it

Comment: It would be better to simply leave out the `*` in the rsync command, but include the slash, otherwise the `vamoot` directory is also trasferred in the path: `rsync -r "/r2g_shared_dir/vamoot"/ ....`

Comment: @wurtel It might be more useful to make that an answer.

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/691980/how-to-customize-the-bash-shell-with-shopt/

Answer (score 6):

It's best to leave the pattern matching to rsync, then you're not depending on whatever shell and options that shell has at that time.

When you do:

```
rsync -a /some/dir/* host:/remote/dir/
```

then you're actually asking the shell to expand the `/some/dir/*` part, so that rsync is actually executed like this:

```
rsync -a /some/dir/adir /some/dir/afile /some/dir/anotherfile [etc] host:/remote/dir/
```

This is usually quite similar to what the intention was, however not always as demonstrated by the fact that this question was asked. Hence it's better to execute:

```
rsync -a /some/dir/ host:/remote/dir/
```

Now rsync will (because `-a` is shorthand for `-rlptgoD` which includes `-r` for recursion) recursively walk through the `/some/dir` directory and sync all its contents to `/remote/dir` on the remote host, including any dot files directly in `/some/dir`.

As the source path ends with a slash `/`, the filenames transferred omit any part of the source location. If `/some/dir` was passed, then you're telling to explicitly sync the `dir` directory, *including* its name. It's recommended to get into the habit of adding the last slash at all times to avoid such confusion, unless you really understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best is to use archive mode (-a), manual pages says about it: "This is equivalent to -rlptgoD. It is a quick way of saying you want recursion and want to preserve almost everything (with -H being a notable omission).":

```
rsync -a /source/path/ /destination/path/
```

- always use ending slash /
- do not use * as it does not include dot files
- if transferring over network that is slower than disk read/write, consider compression -z